# api not loading in ajax method but loading in script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to load the api through `ajax` method..
but when I load it in ajax method its not loading...

if i load it like this

```
<script src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"></script>
```

its loading

providing my code below..

```
var bvapiUrl = window.location.protocol + 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox';
window.loadBazaarvoiceApi = function (callback) {
    if (window.$BV) {
        callback();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: bvapiUrl,
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: function () {
                $($BV.docReady);
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
};
$BV.ui("rr", "show_reviews", {
    productId: "test1"
});
```

HTML::

```
<div id="BVRRContainer">
   <!-- include contents of {DisplayCode}/reviews/product/1/001122.htm if it exists -->
</div>
```

Comment: You could use a protocol-relative URL for your script, i.e. start with `//`. Here's some good information on the subject: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this: `window.location.protocol + 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox';`, so the output is not a valid url because you are adding http or https depending on the protocol, twice.

See: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`

You have to remove the protocol part of your api url.